# Overwrite style in default template

Tags: html, css

I am using wordpress and some plugin theme.Currently my default template contain this attribute.

```
  html {
    margin-top: 32px !important;
}
```

I need to set it to margin 0px.How to override it? I tried to set in in my specific css but can't.

Comment: Add new CSS below the default CSS. the priority is with the last CSS file. then you can rewrite CSS where you want to edit.

Comment: the problem is my new custom css is not behind the default css so I can't overwrite it .

Comment: I didn't have worked with Wordpress but it must be a way to add new CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

`!important` carries the highest level of [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

As such, there are only two ways to overwrite it:

- Add another `!important` declaration later on in the stylesheet: `html { margin-top: 0; }`

```css
html {
  background: red !important;
}

html {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<html></html>
```

- Or add an inline `!important` declaration: `<html style="margin-top: 0 !important;">`

```css
html {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<html style="background: blue !important;"></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put your custom css file below template default css file then browser will affected below css first so template css properties  will be replaced by your custom css. so you can write

```css
 html {
    margin-top: 100px !important;
    background-color:red !important;
}


html {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    background-color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <h1> hello</h1>
</html>
```